# xPath Expression to get total number of Instagram posts of a hashtag

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, instagram

I'm using =IMPORTXML function on Google sheets and trying to get number of total posts for #bepartoflegacy. Here is the link https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/bepartoflegacy/

What is the correct xPath expression to get total posts for this hashtag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the page you are trying to read from contains dynamic html. The problem with this is that the `IMPORTXML` function only reads the raw page source without executing the javascript, and this is the part responsible for creating the `img` tags:

[Can't get the data using importXML from Dynamic Web Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747757/cant-get-the-data-using-importxml-from-dynamic-web-page)

However, in this case I managed to find the following html tag in the raw source:

```
<meta content="329 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from ‘bepartoflegacy’ hashtag" name="description" />
```

So you could use the following function call:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/bepartoflegacy/", "//meta[@name='description']/@content")
```

Comment: Agreed, the page looks like an endless scroller.