# Googlesheets xpath/xquery on nasdaq

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use `importxml()` to get the options table from nasdaq. Here's what I tried:

```
importxml("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/cmg/option-chain", "//tr[@class='option-chain-tables__row']")
```

And

```
importxml("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/cmg/option-chain", "//div[@class='option-chain-tables__row']")
```

And

```
importxml("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/cmg/option-chain", "//span[@class='option-chain-tables__row']")
```

The above formulas didn't work for me, it returned blank with no error. What have I done wrong? I am new to using xpath/xquery.

Comment: I tried to make the question more readable and added tags so that people can see it. Could you add a sample of the data you are querying with these expressions?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Laurenz, Thanks for the edit!  
Jack, my expected output is to get the table content.  
for example:  
LAST CHANGE BID ASK VOLUME STRIKE LAST CHANGE BID ASK VOLUME  
19.9 0.87 0 0 429 200 0.09 -0.04 0 0 1838  
i want to be able to interact with the data on googlesheets like i could on the actual web page, be able to select a date and update the data extracted.  
Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get the data using importXML from Dynamic Web Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747757/cant-get-the-data-using-importxml-from-dynamic-web-page)

Comment: That's a dynamically generated table.

Comment: Alejandro, I did notice that it is dynamic and i did postulate that it was running some script to fill the "&nbsp" with data. I was able to extract the data on chrome browser's console with a few lines of code. I figured if i could do that on Chrome with such ease, why would googlesheets be so difficult. i was using the importhtml function before and it was working perfectly for me. but nasdaq updated their site last week and now it's dynamic. I was hoping that some of you guys (gurus) could figure out a solution to this problem... Thanks for the help! Now i know it's very difficult.