# Pull/parse info from HTML into Google Sheet using XPath

Tags: html, xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to make a first script in Google Sheets to automate a small task in the workplace.

The plan is to have the sheet make a call to a specific URL by combining the page url and a tracking number, e.g. https://t.17track.net/en#nums=NUM123ABC

Then pull relevant data from a specific div relevant to the tracking information box in the result, and fire it back into a cell or cells in Google Sheets.

My question is, can this be done by using XPath on an HTML page such as the one above?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *"[,,,] can this be done by using XPath on an HTML page such as the one above?"* - In this case, no, because the data you are *really* interested in is loaded via Javascript/Ajax in the browser, i.e. it's not part of the HTML source code. You can only query for things with XPath that are part of the actual source code.

Comment: In order to see what you could search via XPath, use the "View Source" function of your browser (e.g. via the right mouse button menu). In this case there is no info at all in the source code that belongs to your tracking number, it's all added dynamically after the page has loaded.

Comment: ...and that means there is nothing to scrape. You can try to use a website's API to query for specific bits of information in a machine-digestible form. Judging from their FAQ, 17track seems to have a non-public/paid API: https://help.17track.net/hc/en-us/articles/235261928. This would be your best bet if creating something that can be used from within Google Sheets is the goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get the data using importXML from Dynamic Web Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747757/cant-get-the-data-using-importxml-from-dynamic-web-page)