# How to get Website Value into Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

From website https://goldenmark.com/pl/mysaver/ceny-zlota/ I want to get bolded value in Aktualny kurs: **6940,28** PLN/uncję into my spreadsheet. How to obtain this?
Thank you

Comment: First try to see if the site provides an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)  to load data. If it doesn't you can use a web scraping such as python beautiful soup or R rvest. Try one of these and ask your question again showing us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could try xpath and the importxml function:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

Comment: I tried by catching CSS class, didn't work:
=IMPORTXML("https://goldenmark.com/pl/mysaver/ceny-zlota/", "//span[contains(@class, stats-rate)]")

Comment: The command looks correct. I took a quick look at the site. The value will only be added later. I suspect it's because it doesn't have a value at query time.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747757/cant-get-the-data-using-importxml-from-dynamic-web-page

Comment: There is Apps Script in Google Sheet. Maybe you can use that for that. Haven't tried it yet but could be an approach.

https://medium.com/@interdigitizer/scrape-and-save-data-to-google-sheets-with-apps-script-7e3c0ccec96b

Answer (score 0):

the element you want to import is controlled by JavaScript.

google sheets is not able to import JS content.

you can always test this by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be scraped